# When I remove item from checkout page in Magento 1.9, its showing error of form key

Tags: magento-1.9, php, error, magento1.9.3, frontend-error

[image]

strong text
when I delete one item its working fine but when I remove the second item then its showing error I didn't know why this is happening please anyone help me?

https://madoverprint.com/madover/index.php

Thanks

Comment: you need to correct url from `checkout/cart/ajaxDelete`  to `ajaxcartsuper/index/cartdelete` on cart page same as mini cart OR send form key while call Ajax.